# Linear Programming - Re-setting a variable based on it's cumulative count

Tags: linear-programming

Detailed business problem:

I'm trying to solve a production scheduling  business problem as below:

1. I have two plants producing FG A and B respectively.
2. Both the products consume the same Raw Material x
3. I need to create a 30 day production schedule looking at the Raw Material availability.
4. FG A and B can be produced if there is sufficient raw material available on the day.
5. After every 6 days of production the plant has to undergo maintenance and the production on that day will be zero.
6. Objective is to maximize the margin looking at the day level Raw material available and adhere to the production constraint (i.e. shutdown after every 6th day)

I need to build a linear programming to address the below problem:

Variable y: (binary)
variable z: cumulative of y

When z > 6 then y = 0. I also need to reset the cumulation of z after this point.

Desired output:

[image]

How can I build the statement to MILP constraint. Are there any techniques for solving this problem. Thank you.

Comment: This does not make much sense to me. Please be more concise. Currently you want *y* to react to some cumulation involving *y* too: *setting y to 0 due to some modulo-hitting cumulation does imply not setting y to 0 due to setting it to 0*. Things would change with an additional column though, decoupling y and processed/clipped/modulo'ed y.

Comment: I have detailed out the business problem for more clarity, hope this helps to set the context better. Appreciate any help you can offer towards the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can model your maintenance differently. Just forbid any sequences of 7 ones for `y`. I.e.

```
 y[t-6]+y[t-5]+y[t-4]+y[t-3]+y[t-2]+y[t-1]+y[t] <= 6 for t=1,..,T
```

This is easier than using your accumulator. Note that the beginning needs some attention: you can use historic data for this. I.e., at `t=1`, the values for `t=0,-1,-2,..` are known.

Your accumulator approach is not inherently wrong. We often use it to model inventory. An inventory capacity is a restriction on how large the accumulated inventory can be.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, this was really helpful. I was able to address the problem with your suggested approach.